# How to select check boxes on load page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to select some of these check boxes on load. I need to be able to select and unselect all check boxes after the page is loaded. So far I tried :$scope.itemSelected = [{ "ItemID": 1, "ItemName": "Item 1" }];

```
        div ng-repeat="item in itemItems">
            <md-checkbox ng-checked="existsItem(item, itemSelected);" ng-click="toggleItem(item, itemSelected);" value="{{item.ItemID}}">
                {{item.ItemName}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </div>

angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AdminController', function ($scope) {

$scope.itemItems = [{ "ItemID": 1, "ItemName": "Item 1" }, { "ItemID": 2, "ItemName": "Item 2" },
    { "ItemID": 3, "ItemName": "Item 3" }, { "ItemID": 4, "ItemName": "Item 4" },
    { "ItemID": 5, "ItemName": "Item 5" }];
$scope.itemSelected = [];

$scope.toggleItem = function (item, list) {
    var idx = list.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) {
        list.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        list.push(item);
    }
};

$scope.existsItem = function (item, list) {
    return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
};
})
```

Comment: You have defined a goal, but not a specific problem or question related to your code. Please read through [ask]. You normally use `ng-model` for checkbox state. Also we have no idea what `itemSelected` is, it's not defined anywhere

Comment: Thank you . I am passing itemSelected as an argument to toggleItem

Comment: Better not to use javascript with angular....

Comment: But what is `itemSelected`? it appears from nowhere in code shown. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @MukulSharma that comment makes absolutely no sense....angular ***is*** javascript. Please refrain from non constructive vague comments

Answer (score 0):

This is rather bugs with ng-checked in angular material version below 1.1.1 but it has already fixed in version 1.1.1.  Refer changelog at this link https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md .If you want to use ng-check please grab the latest version.

Alternatively, you can use ng-model to check and uncheck the checkboxes. By manipulating your array to add checked attribute, you can manipulate it to be false or true and use this attribute as ng-model in the checkbox. Thanks.

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemItems">
       <md-checkbox ng-checked="existsItem(item, itemSelected);" ng-click="toggleItem(item, itemSelected);" 
                 ng-model="item.checked" value="{{item.ItemID}}">
                {{item.ItemName}}
       </md-checkbox>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.itemItems = [{ "ItemID": 1, "ItemName": "Item 1", "checked":true}, { "ItemID": 2, "ItemName": "Item 2" , "checked":false},
    { "ItemID": 3, "ItemName": "Item 3", "checked":false }, { "ItemID": 4, "ItemName": "Item 4" , "checked":false},
    { "ItemID": 5, "ItemName": "Item 5", "checked":false }];
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion works but to unselect a checkbox I have to click twice. How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm also experience this before. I think it has been fixed in angular material version 2. Please see this issue, https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/672

Comment: Try use ng-change instead of ng-click

Comment: ng-change doesn't work and unfortunately I can not use material 2 because I am working with angular 1.

Comment: I think it's conflict with ng-check or ng-click. You try to remove either one of them and see the changes.

Comment: If I remove ng-checked works, but I need to enter in the database the checked. If I use an integer array I can select directly like:$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; $scope.selected = [1,3];. Can I select like that an object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136615/discussion-between-user6440175-and-digit).